# Scala characteristic function

Tags: scala

We got three functions. The first one defines type alias for Boolean condition

```
type Set = Int => Boolean
```

I understand that this is the alias definition. Now the second fucntion

```
def contains(set: Set, elem: Int): Boolean = set(elem)
```

calls the `(Int=>Boolean)` on `elem:Int`.

- **QUESTION 1**: Where is the logic of the function under `Set`?
- I mean, do I have to pass the `Set` function actual parameter (in which case the `contains` is a higher order function) when calling `contains` eg. for even numbers set:

  `val in:Boolean = contains({x=>(x%2)==0},2)`

---

In the third function:

```
def singletonSet(elem: Int): Set = set => set == elem
```

- **Question 2:** Where does the `set` come form? Its not in the formal parameter list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**QUESTION 1:** Yes, you have to pass a `Set` which would be the "implementation" of the function. The point of this exercise (Odersky's course?) is to show that a Set can be defined not as a collection of items (the "usual" definition of a set), but rather as a function that says whether an item is included in the set or not. So **the Set *is* the function**.

**QUESTION 2:** `set` is the name given to the argument of the anonymous function we're returning here: Since `singletonSet`'s return type is `Set`, which as we've said is actually a function of type `Int => Boolean`, we return an (anonymous) function. To create such a function, one uses the syntax `x => f(x)`, where `x` is any name you'd like and `f(x)` is an expression using it (or not).

Comment: 1) Undersood
2) If `Set` is returned from `singletonSet` than its actually `Int=>Boolean` what is being returned. So the `set` here is `Int`? How would the call to the `singletonSet` for a set of even numbers looked like?

Comment: Yeah, in (2), `set` has type `Int`. `singletonSet` _cannot_ return the set of even numbers - it's called singleton because it always returns a set with only one item (one integer), which is the `elem` passed to it.

Comment: So its like the returning type of `Set` in the `singletonSet` is some kind of evaluation of `Int=>Boolean` changed to expresion `set:Int=>(set:Int==elem:Int)`?

Comment: (almost) correct, the method body can be equivalently written as `candidate: Int => candidate == elem`, which has the type `Int => Boolean`, which has the alias `Set`.

Answer (score 2):

1) Since a `Set` is a function, `contains` is indeed a higher order function which takes a function and an element of the appropriate type and applies the function to the element. The logic of it is that sets are being represented by Boolean-valued functions where an element evaluates to `true` if and only if it is in the corresponding set. The function `contains` evaluates the function at the element and returns its value, which is either `true` or `false` depending on whether or not it is in the set.

2) `singleton` returns an anonymous function, one that evaluates to `true` if and only if the input (`set`) equals the element in question.

Comment: 2) But what is this `set` ? Where does it come form? Its not mentioned anywhere ?

Comment: `set` stands for the input to the anonymous function. The declaration of `Set` (which is the return type of `singletonSet`)  is enough for Scala to infer that `set` is an `Int`. The way anonymous functions work, you don't have to declare the input parameters.